# How can i store a continous output into a full string?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, binary-tree

For the code below I'm trying to get the printed node to be stored in a string in a full expression within the variable `s`.

```
string ExprTree::prefixOrder(const ExprTree & t){
    string s;
    if (t.root != NULL){
     s.append(t.root->toString());
     prefixOrder(t.root->getLeftChild());
     prefixOrder(t.root->getRightChild());
    }
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
      return s;
}
```

For an arithmetic expression i.e `5 + 5`

I get the output:

```
5
5
+
```

However, I want to store this in string `s` in a complete string like `"+ 5 5"` but appending stores the output in different elements and not in a single string so I was wondering how I can achieve this outcome? I tried using `stringstream` and ran into the same problem.

Comment: The currently-discarded return results from your recursions is going to be helpful in achieving what you seem to be seeking. Try using them. And I'm curious how you get any "output" from *this* code.

Comment: I edited the OP. The problem is i'm trying to get the outputted strings stored in a single string variable and outputted in a single line like this " + 5 5 ". I'm not really sure how the recursion result would help me achieve this.

Comment: `std::ostringstream` is the correct answer here. "Ran into the same problem" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks i got it to work. Guess i haven't conceptualised recursion that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation discards any string-building done by the recursions, leaving their caller with effectively nothing to show for their efforts. It should look something like this:

```
std::string ExprTree::prefixOrder(const ExprTree & t)
{
    std::string s;
    if (t.root != NULL)
    {
        s.append(t.root->toString());
        s.append(prefixOrder(t.root->getLeftChild()));
        s.append(prefixOrder(t.root->getRightChild()));
    }
    return s;
}
```

With that, given your root expression tree, you will get the prefix order as the final output. The root caller will look simply like this:

```
ExprTree tree;

//
// build tree...
//

std::cout << prefixOrder(tree) << '\n';
```